# Huge app with webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am planing to develop a huge app (Let's say more than 100 pages with a lot of JS charts and maps) using React, React-Router and Webpack. I believe the size of final JS file is going to be so large and that is going to be so annoying for User during first page load.

Is there any way to load the final JS partially, for example based on the selected route? or I should stick to server-side rendering and using some other libraries like PJAX? I appreciate any other solution as well.

Comment: Look into code splitting with webpack: https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html. You might want to take a look at AST explorer: https://github.com/fkling/astexplorer. It's a tool to visualize the AST produced by different parsers. But of course we cannot bundle all the parsers into a single file, since that file would be huge and most people only use a single parser anyway. So they are loaded on demand.

Comment: Thanks Felix, That was so helpful